# How can I call a push button from another pushbutton in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, callback

I have a simple GUI containing two pushbuttons, one to play the cam stream and the other to stop it.

```
function Play_callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)

Play1 = evalin('base','PlayCam1');
Play2 = evalin('base','PlayCam2');

while (1)
if(Play1 == 1)
...CAM1 STREAM...
end
if(Play2 == 1)
...CAM2 STREAM...
end
end

function StopCam1(hObject,eventdata,handles)
assignin('base','PlayCam1',0);
Play_callback(hObject,eventdata,handles);
```

The above code snip streams both cams on pushbutton `"Play"`, but I need to control the `"STOP"` of each cam indvidually, so if I click `"StopCam1"`, the `"PlayCam1"` is equal to `0`, and calls again the `"Play"` pushbutton to stream cam2 not cam1. MATLAB just freezes, why is that ?

Comment: Does your "while (1)" ever finish?

Comment: Thats the point.. I need a way to exit it when i call the "Stop" and call it back in again

Comment: You could do while (Play1 || Play2) instead - while either Play1 or Play2 are 1, do your cam streams?

I'm not sure that the Stop callback will be executed if your Play callback includes a loop and so never finishes - as far as I'm aware, the callbacks are placed on a stack an executed sequentially (someone else may correct me on this?). Could you place your loop outside of the callback, and just set the callback to set Play1 and Play2?

Comment: Can you explain what are you doing in `CAM STREAM`? Does it include any processing (or how long does each iteration take)? Should it run with a certain or fixed frequency? Why have you put that part in a `while`? For example if it takes ~0.001 sec for each iteration, you are running in 1000 Hz. Is that necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign your Play1 and Play2 variables in your while loop:

```
function Play_callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)

Play1 = evalin('base','PlayCam1');
Play2 = evalin('base','PlayCam2');

while (1)
Play1 = evalin('base','PlayCam1');
Play2 = evalin('base','PlayCam2');
if(Play1 == 1)
...CAM1 STREAM...
end
if(Play2 == 1)
...CAM2 STREAM...
end
end
```

or

```
function Play_callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)

while (1)
if(evalin('base','PlayCam1')== 1)
...CAM1 STREAM...
end
if(evalin('base','PlayCam2')== 1)
...CAM2 STREAM...
end
end
```